# Allowing decimal no input to a textbox and validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox that needs to accept decimal number input, and disallow other characters and dot entry if more than once.I used the below approach for the same

```
$('#BankEMI').keydown(function (e) {
        var key1 = e.keyCode;
        if (key1 == 190 || key1 == 110) {
            var s = $('#BankEMI').val();
            if (s.indexOf('.') > - 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
        if (key1 == 13 || key1 == 8 || key1 == 9 || key1 == 46 || (key1 >= 35 && key1 <= 40)) {
            return true
        }
        if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
            e.preventDefault()
        } else {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (!((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        }
    })
});
```

BankEMI- is the input box.
I need to support number of kind 4100.50
I haven't put any restriction on decimal places as of now, cause I round up the value to 2 decimal places later in my calculation. So if user inputs 4100.524 it will be rounded and used.
Can there be any more simpler way to handle this?

Comment: Please provide example of which decimals fits your needs and which one don't.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use regex to perform this task.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Might be better to include more information in your answer and not rely on an link to another page. It is possible the link will stop working in the future, and thus the answer won't be so useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I use it in my numeric forms, but this does not account for pasting erroneous text with multiple decimal points (ex. "123.123.123")

```
$(':text').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var $this = $( this ),
    kWhich = e.which,
    kCode = e.keyCode,
    kChar = e.key,
    validKeys = [8, 46, 37, 39, 36, 35, 9 ], // backspace, del, left, right, home, end, tab
  ctrChars = new RegExp(/[vax]/gi);

    if (!(kChar.match( /[\d\.]/g ) || validKeys.indexOf(kCode) >= 0 || (e.ctrlKey && kChar.match(ctrChars))) || e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

  // Prevent multiple decimal points
  if (kChar.match(/\./gmi) && $this.val().match(/\./gmi))
    e.preventDefault();

  console.log('====\nkey:' + kChar+ '\nwhich:' + kWhich + '\nkeyCode:' + kCode);
}).on('paste', function(e) {
  var clipBoard = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
  console.log('paste:' + clipBoard);
  if (clipBoard.replace(/[\d\.]/gim, '').length > 0 || (clipBoard.match(/\./g) || []).length > 1)
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wasqroqj/1/).

Comment: its working fine, except that it is taking the pasted text with more than 1 decimal value.

Comment: Updated code and fiddle link to only accept 1 decimal point for pasted values, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Id from input tag is "myID" and this method which i have tried is validating your condition and it looks bit more logical.

```
$("#myID").keydown(function(){

str=$("#myID").val();

if(isNaN(str) || ((str.indexOf('.')==-1)  && str.indexOf('.')!=str.lastIndexOf('.'))){
console.log("invalid")
}
});
```